# Running .NET Core application in Docker container with memory limit

Tags: c#, docker, memory

I testing different limits of Docker containers with the help of C#. For testing purposes, I write a simple program that generates different types of loads (CPU-bound work, memory allocations, network requests, etc).

For the scenarious with many memory allocations I write following code:

```
try {
    var chunks = new byte[10][];
    for (var chunkId = 0; chunkId < 10; chunkId++) {
        Console.WriteLine($"Chunk: {chunkId}");
        var chunk = new byte[100 * 1024 * 1024];
        for (var i = 0; i < chunk.Length; i++)
            chunk[i] = (byte) (i % 256);
        chunks[chunkId] = chunk;
    }
}
catch (Exception) { // To capture OutOfMemoryException and pause the process
    Thread.CurrentThread.Join();
}
```

This code allocated 10 chunks of 100MB contiguous segments of memory (1GB in total), but the magic happens when I run it inside the container with memory restrictions:

```
$> docker run --memory=1g --memory-swap=1g <workload-image>
```

In the container with RAM limited to 1GB, my application can allocate only 6-7 chunks of 100MB, and request to the new byte array failed with `OutOfMemoryException`.

At first, I thought, that CLR consumes memory for some internal structures, but after hours of digging into the memory dumps, I don't find any suspicious large objects in the .NET heap.

Finally, I set up the following simple experiment. I run my application in the Docker container with a 1GB RAM limit, and after `OutOfMemoryException` is handled in my `catch` statement and process paused, I run another copy of my program, which suddenly can allocate 3 additional chunks of memory (300MB).

I can't explain why my application can't allocate all chunks (or at least 9/10 chunks) with 1GB RAM limit. Can anybody shed the light on this mysterious behavior of .NET?

Problem reproduced with Docker Desktop (Windows 10, 5GB RAM of memory preallocated) and docker 19.03.11 in Ubuntu 18.10.
My project targets `netcoreapp3.1` and final image based on the `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1.300`. I push [my image](https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/sivukhin/stackoverflow-csharp-mem) in the Docker hub registry, if this can be helpful in the investigation of problem.

**UPD**: I write a simple analog of C# application in C++ and it successfully runs with 1GB limits. So, I think this is something tightly related to the .NET CLR.

Also, in the container application consumes 724 MB according to top (`RES` column):

```
PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND    
  1 root      20   0 5749076 741512  19932 S   0.0   9.3   0:01.05 dotnet
```

Comment: There is a similiar issue on Docker's github, no solutions right now: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/2514

Comment: Yes, I saw that issue, but it looks different from my question. 
My application targets `netcoreapp3.1` and runs in the image, which based on `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1.300`. And issue reproduces with Docker Desktop (Windows) and with docker in usual unix ecosystem (Ubuntu 18.10)

Comment: How do you know you allocate contiguous memory?  You  absolutely could have fragmentation which leads to OOM exceptions when a contiguous block of the needed size is not available. Also, system memory does not equate one-to-one with memory available to your process so you cannot expect your program to have access to every byte.

Comment: @Crowcoder, I thought about fragmentation but can't find any signs of high fragmentation of memory. And I can't understand, how your points explain behaviour with the second instance of my application that can allocate 300MB of memory...

Comment: Manged memory is a virtual address space. A 64 bit application can address 8TB of memory. That memory is an abstraction over RAM and swap file and that is over-simplifying because I am far from expert. But my point is that memory != RAM.

Comment: Yes, I understand that there are many levels of abstractions, but I don't quite understand the reason for `OutOfMemoryException` in my example. If this is because of high fragmentation - then why I can run another process that consumes remained 300MB (also using 3 chunks of 100 MB). If this is some limitation of the kernel - then why I can run the C++ program, which successfully allocates 1GB in a similar environment.

Comment: Another process does not share the same memory space. C++ is not managed and I have considerably less knowledge of it than .net.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HeapHardLimit is 75% of container memory limit by default, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/run-time-config/garbage-collector#heap-limit

So with a 1GB container limit, you should be able to allocate 7x100MB chunks in a single dotnet process.

Comment: Wow, thank you for the answer! Miss this configuration setting - I think that option explain my experimental results.